# Passing a hash to i18n translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm in the proccess of creating notification system. System should notify user about some changes in models, ie this is my `.yml` file

```
ru:
  notifications:
    task: "New task named %{notifiable.task_name}"
    order: "New order with price %{notifiable.price}"
```

You understand now that I have a associations `User has_many Notification` and `Notification has_one(polymorphic) Notifiable`. So, you understand that `Order` hasn't attribute `task_name` and `Task` hasn't attribute `price`. How can I pass a hash to i18n or implement this logic another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ok understood that!

Please consider code below:

```
# making a hash
def serialized_message_object
  attr_hash = {}
  @user.attribute_names.each { |attr_name| attr_hash[('user_' + attr_name).to_sym] = @user[attr_name] }
  @user.attribute_names.each { |attr_name| attr_hash[('notifiable_' + attr_name).to_sym] = @notifiable[attr_name] }
  attr_hash 
end

# call I18n
I18n.t('notifications.' + message_type, serialized_message_object)

# i18n
ru:
  notifications:
    task: "New task named %{notifiable_task_name}"
    order: "New order with price %{notifiable_price}"
```